# In a street /in the street

Tags: word-usage

Would a native speaker say  "in the streets" instead of "in a street"  when not talking about a specific street?

"I never played in the streets/in a street when I was a child."

Comment: Depends on context. Please give more. Also, probably depends on the neighborhood.

Comment: I think the more commonly heard sentence goes like: "I never played on the streets as a child."

Comment: In UK English, 'in the street', doesn't have to be about any particular street. you can talk about types of location generically using 'the'.  You can use your mobile phone in the street, in the bus, or in the bath.

Comment: For AmE, the phrase "in the streets" when applied to living beings, usually means in the place where cars normally go; whereas "on the streets" is vaguer and can refer to the sidewalk as well.  When talking about vehicles, "in the street" can also more narrowly apply to the place where cars move, as opposed the place where they are parked, but usage fluctuates.

Comment: Another UK meaning of 'in the street' is 'homeless', e.g. if I don't pay my rent, I'll end up in the street'.

Comment: @Michael Harvey, it should be "in the street" I cannot say "in the streets" instead of " in the street" in this sense you mentioned. Right?  "in UK English, 'in the street', doesn't have to be about any particular street. you can talk about types of location generically using 'the"

Answer (score 1):

There are almost certainly regional variants involved, but **in the street** is probably the usage you're looking for, to refer to all streets (as opposed to sidewalks) in the abstract, in "I never played in **the street**."

But note, changing from singular to plural, or changing the preposition, can create phrases with established meanings: "on the street" can mean homeless. "The streets" can refer to low-income urban environments and their culture.